# Rails Database Associations Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've read a few of the help topics and the ruby documentation on PolyMorphic Associations and am still not sure if that is the way to go.  After struggling with the concept and trying to figure this out, I thought of reaching out here.

What I tried so far was this, which breaks all other CRUD operations from happening in the libraries and departments models.

**Normal Hours Class**

```
class NormalHour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Library Class**

```
class Library < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :departments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :normal_hours, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy

  def departments
      departments = Department.where(:library_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

**Departments Class**

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :library, inverse_of: :departments
  has_many :normal_hours, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The problem becomes that after adding those I can no longer add or delete anything from the libraries or departments.

Any thoughts?  Tutorials?  Samples?  Etc?

[image]

### UPDATE

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| resource_type | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| resource_id   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| day_of_week   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| open          | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| close         | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

## UPDATE 2

It appears that I'm having issues with the views now, but simplifying the view and modifying my Library and Department classes has fixed my original problem.  Now I'm trying to figure out the best case scenario for making a dynamic form that changes the type based on selected object and loads both libraries and departments into a select field.

*removed* `dependent: :destroy`

**Library Class**

```
class Library < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :departments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :normal_hours, as: :resource

  def departments
      departments = Department.where(:library_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

**Departments Class**

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :library, inverse_of: :departments
  has_many :normal_hours, as: :resource
end
```

## UPDATE 3

#### Problem Update:

After Update 2 I think my true problem is figuring out the views for this stuff.  I know that the department and library classes will have access to normal_hours information.  The problem that I'm having is in entering the data through forms and using that same form to update that data.

```
  <div class="field" >
    <%= f.collection_select(:resource_id, Library.all, :id, :name)  %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select(:resource_id, Department.all, :id, :reformat_name) %>
  </div>
```

I need a condition to turn off the fields or hide the fields based on the type of information being entered.  I thought about putting a check button or question that uses JS to hide/show the correct drop down, but what kind of a logic do I need to change the specific class based on the type or is there a better way.

I was thinking that potentiall in the collection_select I could use the reference type to call the class `@normal_hours.resource_type.all` but I doubt that would instantiate a new class.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: Why do you have `def departments` in your Library class?

Comment: When I try to destroy an object I get an SQL error saying that select * from normal_hours WHERE id = 3 doesn't exist.

Comment: def departments was put in because library.departments was not already in the model for some reason so it gets the departments and lists them in the view.  That part is working correctly although there may be a better way to do it. I'm new to rails so it could be something I'm doing.

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking the association, does the model get regenerated to automatically handle deleting of records if the department or library were to be deleted?

Comment: The ERD leads me to think that your polymorphic setup isn't correct (unless that's an artifact of the drawing tool not understanding polymorphism).  Can you confirm that you have resource_id and resource_type as attributes of your NormalHour class?

Comment: Might be my drawing, I did notice that the database wasn't migrating properly, but this was the updated mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the schema wrong for polymorphic associations.  Take a look at the [rails guide on polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).  Your normal_hours table should have two fields: resource_id and resource_type.  Using those two keys, a NormalHour can belong to either a Library or a Department.  In one case, the values in those fields would be "5" and "Library" and the other case "12" and "Department".   The schema in your picture is not polymorphic - its simply that NormalHour can belong to either of those.

This could could be causing problems as well:

```
def departments
  departments = Department.where(:library_id => self.id)
 end
```

That is overriding the definition of departments with the has_many association.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try again with your suggestions and see if I can't get something working.

Comment: I've added the MySQL table.

Comment: How do I get the definition of departments to work with the has_many association? I had to define the departments method in my class because it wasn't available without defining it.

Comment: @DavidJ.Davis Your department association should work. What exactly do you mean by - _it wasn't available_ ?

Comment: @Magnuss in the view trying to access it with the following `<% library.departments.each do |dept| %>
            <li> <%= dept.name %> </li>
          <% end %>`

Library itself is coming from the loop of @libraries